# Oracle updating a column to the last date of the current month

Tags: sql, oracle

Fairly simple issue I'm probably just messing up the syntax somewhere. I'm trying to set a column to the last day of the current month.

This is the SQL statement I wrote:

```
UPDATE table1
SET END_DATE = (SELECT LAST_DAY(to_date(sysdate, 'MM/DD/YYYY')) 
                FROM dual)
WHERE user_id = 1;
```

I keep getting this error:

> [Error] Execution (7: 42): ORA-01843: not a valid month.

I expected to get the `end_date` column set to 2/29/2024

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sysdate` is already a date, you should not use `TO_DATE()` on it.
Try something like this:

```
SET END_DATE =  (SELECT LAST_DAY(sysdate) from dual)
```

Comment: awesome that did the trick, I figured i was off with something silly

Comment: Or even `SET END_DATE =  LAST_DAY(sysdate)` There is no reason to select from dual

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, a `DATE` is a binary data-type composed of 7 bytes representing century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second. It **ALWAYS** has those components and is **NEVER** stored in any-particular human readable format.

You may not see the time component as the client application you are using may default to only showing the date-component of the `DATE` and does not display the time-component; that does not mean that it is not there (only that it is not being displayed by the client).

The `LAST_DAY` function will update the day byte to be the last day of the month but will not change the year, month or time components of the date. Therefore, if you use:

```sql
UPDATE table1
SET   END_DATE = LAST_DAY(SYSDATE)
WHERE user_id = 1;
```

You will set the date to the last day of the current month with the time component equal to the current time of day; you probably do not want that.

For example, given the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (user_id, end_date) AS
  SELECT 1, DATE '1970-01-01' FROM DUAL;
```

Then after the update, the table contains:

| USER_ID | END_DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024-02-29 11:16:10 |

---

Instead, if you want to set the value to midnight of the last day of the month:

```sql
UPDATE table1
SET   END_DATE = LAST_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE))
WHERE user_id = 1;
```

Then the table would contain:

| USER_ID | END_DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024-02-29 00:00:00 |

---

If you want to set the value to the last second of the last day of the month (i.e. at 23:59:59) then:

```sql
UPDATE table1
SET   END_DATE = ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), 1) - INTERVAL '1' SECOND
WHERE user_id = 1;
```

or:

```sql
UPDATE table1
SET END_DATE = TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM') + INTERVAL '1' MONTH - INTERVAL '1' SECOND
WHERE user_id = 1;
```

or:

```sql
UPDATE table1
SET   END_DATE = LAST_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE)) + INTERVAL '23:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND
WHERE user_id = 1;
```

After any of those three statements, the table will contain:

| USER_ID | END_DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024-02-29 23:59:59 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/acTnmvas)